# How can I get a 2 second printing delay in a textarea between each letter/key that is pressed in another textarea?

Tags: java, netbeans

I'm trying to add a 2 second delay between each letter that is typed in one textarea before it is printed/displayed on another textarea.

I've used two classes:

- One for a GUI called Printdelay
- One for the thread, called TwoSecondDelay

Everything works fine except for the execution of the thread.

Here's the code for the GUI:

```
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;
import java.awt.event.KeyListener;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JTextArea;


public class PrintDelay extends javax.swing.JFrame implements KeyListener{

    int name;

    JTextArea server = new JTextArea (10, 20);
    JTextArea client = new JTextArea (10, 20);


    public PrintDelay () {

        super ("Typing...");

        setSize (650, 220);
        setDefaultCloseOperation (JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        JPanel panel = new JPanel ();

        server.addKeyListener (this);

        panel.add (server);
        panel.add (client);
        add(panel);

        setVisible (true);

    }

    public static void main (String... args) {

        new PrintDelay ();

    }


    @Override
    public void keyTyped(KeyEvent e)
    {

    }

    @Override
    public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e)
    {

    }

    @Override
    public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e)
    {
        new TwoSecondDelay (Integer.toString(name));
        name++;
        client.setText(server.getText());
    }

}
```

Here's the code for the TwoSecondDelay:

```
public class TwoSecondDelay implements Runnable{

    String name;
    Thread t;

    TwoSecondDelay (String threadname) {

        name = threadname;
        t = new Thread (this, name);
        t.start();

    }


    @Override
    public void run() {

        try {
                Thread.sleep(2000);
        } 
        catch (InterruptedException e) {

        }

    }

}
```

Also the classes are in their own separate files.

Comment: What is your specific question?

Comment: How can I get a 2 second printing delay in a textarea between each letter/key that is pressed in another textarea?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No need to use TwoSecondDelay

```
@Override
public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e)
{
    typeText();
    /*new TwoSecondDelay (Integer.toString(name));
    name++;
    client.setText(server.getText());*/

}

public void typeText(){
    ActionListener listener = new ActionListener(){
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event){
            client.setText(server.getText());
        }
    };
    Timer timer = new Timer(2000, listener);
    timer.setRepeats(false);
    timer.start();
}
```

Comment: Thumbs Up :) Thank You!